# Debian 8: grub rescue attempting Boot from Hard Drive: unknow filesystem

Tags: linux, boot, debian, grub

my debian 8 Pc tried to boot on a bad usb hardrive and I am now experiencing the following error:

```
Attempting Boot from Hard Drive: unknow filesystem
Entrering rescue mode..
grub rescue >
```

I run `ls` command:

```
grub rescue > ls
(hd0)
(hd0, msdos5)
(hd0, msdos1)
(fd0)

ls (hd0): Filesytem is unknown
ls (hd0,msdos5): Filesytem is unknown
ls (hd0,msdos1): Filesytem is unknown
ls (fd0) : Filesytem is unknown
error : failure reading sector 0x2 from 'fd0'
```

How can I fix that?